# How can we disable antd table's checkboxes based on condition?

Tags: reactjs, checkbox, antd

For example there are n no of records I want to enable only selected checboxed reamining all records should be disabled automatically?
please check this below my getCheckboxProps() function check is wrong unable to solve it

[Sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/selection-and-operation-ant-design-demo-forked-cyoxv?file=/index.js)

I wanted to disable all non selected checkboxes and here I have no of checboxes can be enabled length we should not cross that length.In my case remaining_total variable.Can anyone help me in right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Your provided link was broken, however one way to disabled **all** the checkbox in antd table row is to return `{disabled: true}` on `getCheckboxProps` function on each cycle. If you have a unique key or item, you can use that to disable specific row, just return `{disabled: true}` if meet a condition. Here's sample on **enabling** the first two rows checkbox:

```
const data = [
  {
    key: "1",
    name: "John Brown",
    age: 32,
    address: "New York No. 1 Lake Park"
  },
  {
    key: "2",
    name: "Jim Green",
    age: 42,
    address: "London No. 1 Lake Park"
  },
  {
    key: "3",
    name: "Joe Black",
    age: 32,
    address: "Sidney No. 1 Lake Park"
  },
  {
    key: "4",
    name: "Bon Jov",
    age: 99,
    address: "Sidney No. 1 Lake Park"
  },
  {
    key: "5",
    name: "User 5",
    age: 99,
    address: "Sidney No. 1 Lake Park"
  },
  {
    key: "6",
    name: "User 6",
    age: 99,
    address: "Sidney No. 1 Lake Park"
  }
];

const rowSelection = {
  getCheckboxProps: (record) => {
    const rowIndex = data.findIndex((item) => item.key === record.key);
    return {
      disabled: rowIndex > 1 //enable first 2 rows only
    };
  }
};
```

Here is a sample of disabling the first 4 rows:

```
const rowSelection = {
  getCheckboxProps: (record) => {
    const rowIndex = data.findIndex((item) => item.key === record.key);
    return {
      disabled: rowIndex < 4 //disable the first 4 rows only
    };
  }
};
```

Here's a working sample:

[image: Edit]

Comment: thanks for the solution I have updated my question Can you please check

Comment: how to disable multiple rows in specific indexes